# List azure file shares snapshots with node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, snapshot, storage-file-share

Is there any way to list in node.js the list of snapshots that a file share has?

Example code:

```
const { ShareServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-file-share");
const credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT,AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY);
const shareServiceClient = new ShareServiceClient(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING,credential);
var shareName = "xxxxx";
var shareClient = shareServiceClient.getShareClient(shareName);

// Create a snapshot:
await shareClient.createSnapshot();
```

How to list the snapshots that this `shareName` has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such there's no special method to list snapshots for a file share. You will need to call [`listShares`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-share/shareserviceclient?view=azure-node-latest#listShares_ServiceListSharesOptions_) method of [`ShareServiceClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-share/shareserviceclient?view=azure-node-latest)
([`@azure/storage-file-share version 12.5.0`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-file-share)) with `includeSnapshots` parameter as `true` and `prefix` as the share name.

Here's the sample code to do so (untested code):

```
const shareName = 'share-name';
const listingOptions = {
    prefix: shareName,
    includeSnapshots: true
};
shareServiceClient.listShares(listingOptions).byPage().next()
.then((result) => {
    const shareItems = result.value.shareItems;
    //Filter results where name of the share is same as share name and is a snapshot
    const shareSnapshots = shareItems.filter(s => s.name === shareName && s.snapshot && s.snapshot !== '');
    console.log(shareSnapshots);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: Thats correct. This way works. Here a code:
var shareName = "xxx";
const listingOptions = {prefix: shareName,includeSnapshots: true};
shareIter = shareServiceClient.listShares(listingOptions);
shareItem = await shareIter.next();
while (!shareItem.done) 
{
  console.log(`Share ${i++}: ${shareItem.value.name} ${shareItem.value.snapshot}`);
  shareItem = await shareIter.next();
}